# Client cannot connect to SignalR hub of a Blazor WebAssembly app running on IIS hosting environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, signalr, blazor

I have created a Blazor WebAssembly Solution according to [This Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor-webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-hosted-blazor-webassembly-app-project).
The index page (code below, unchanged from tutorial):

1. Works on VS2019 dev environment.
2. On another PC I deploy to (machine2, Win10 pro), the page **also works correctly on localhost:5000** (if I launch it ouside of IIS using the command **dotnet AppName.dll**)
3. However on that PC (machine2), **on IIS hosting the SignalR is not connecting** (the page loads when connecting to the public URL, but the button to send a SignalR message is disabled, because IsConnected is false, and it REALLY IS DISCONNECTED).
4. A **ConsoleApp** with identical code (see code at the bottom), has **no problem connecting** from machine1 to the public URL (on machine2), proving that **the SignalR hub itself is running correctly**.

**What is causing this?
How can I debug the client side?**

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        User:
        <input @bind="_userInput" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>
        Message:
        <input @bind="_messageInput" size="50" />
    </label>
</div>
<button @onclick="Send" disabled="@(!IsConnected)">Send</button>

<hr>

<ul id="messagesList">
    @foreach (var message in _messages)
    {
    <li>@message</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    private HubConnection _hubConnection;
    private List<string> _messages = new List<string>();
    private string _userInput;
    private string _messageInput;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chatHub"))
            .Build();

        _hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
        {
            var encodedMsg = $"{user}: {message}";
            _messages.Add(encodedMsg);
            StateHasChanged();
        });

        await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    Task Send() =>
        _hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", _userInput, _messageInput);

    public bool IsConnected =>
        _hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;
}
```

Below is a console app bare minimum that connects to the public signalR hub without any problems.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
namespace ConsoleSignalRDebug
{
    class Program
    {
        static private HubConnection _hubConnection;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .WithUrl("https://myblazorSite.com:443/chatHub")
                    .Build();
                _hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
                { Console.WriteLine("/////////////RECEIVED///////////////" + user + " " + message);});
                _hubConnection.StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                string x = Console.ReadLine();
                _hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", x, x);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this for debugging but it only works on the console (that works anyways):

```
_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .WithUrl("https://myblazorSite.com:443/chatHub")
                    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                    {
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                    logging.AddConsole();
                        })
                    .Build();
```

Comment: Have you enabled websockets? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1
"WebSockets must be enabled (See the IIS/IIS Express support section.)."

Comment: Just enabled them and now it works. Amazing. You may add this as the answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSockets is enabled by default on IISExpress (used for local testing) but disabled by default on full-fat IIS.

So when deploying an application using WebSockets, such as SignalR (or server-side Blazor) you need to enable WebSockets on IIS.

The instructions for enabling IIS WebSockets are found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1#iisiis-express-support